# synchronize contents of textbox of two clients

Tags: javascript, ajax, html

I am a new bee in AJAX.I want to know how to refresh contents of a text box automatically from a text file.that is how to use SetInterval Function to refresh contents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**write a function which do task related to refresh**

```
function refresh_content()
{
  .....
}
```

> var refresher=setInterval(refresh_content,time_in_millisecond);

set time_in_millisecond as interval when it shall refresh the content. setInterval call repeatedly until you call clearInterval.

if you want to stop refreshing

> clearInterval(refresher);

Comment: Did it with sharedjs,which was way easier .